# Detect when contenteditable div has multiple lines of text

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I am using a `contenteditable` on my page. When the user focuses the div, the height is set in js. (Needed to show buttons irreverent to the this issue) If the user types a significant amount of text, as to push multiple lines, it overflows the box and is hidden. How can I detect when additional lines are added or removed? Thanks!

---

HTML: `<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">I can be edited.</div>`

jQuery:

```
$("#edit").focus(function(){
    t=$(this);
    t.css('height',t.height()+10);
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).css('height','');  
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8D4b/

Comment: change your `height` to `min-height` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/f8D4b/5/

Comment: you don't even need the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method, it sets the height to "auto" to override the css setting, then sets the height after each keyup event ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/f8D4b/6/)):

```
$("#edit").on('focus keyup', function () {
    var t = $(this);
    t.css('height', 'auto');
    t.css('height', t.height() + 10);
}).on('blur', function () {
    $(this).css('height', '');
});
```

Comment: Works for me. The only issue is that if the user holds down a key, the new height doesn't fire until the actual `keyup`. Thanks!

Comment: You can change the binding to `keydown` instead.

Comment: It still won't fire after each character. I don't believe there is an event for that. You'd have to use a very short interval and constantly check the length.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to detect when additional lines are added or removed, you just need to modify the following code.

```
$("#edit").focus(function(){
    t=$(this);
    t.css('min-height',t.height()+10);
}).blur(function(){
  $(this).css('min-height','');  
});
```

Check the update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8D4b/2/)

Comment: Make sure that fiddle has the same line you have in your post: `$(this).css('min-height',''); `

Comment: I think what is desired is that the div collapses when it doesn't have focus.

Comment: The only problem with this code is that the div won't maintain the 10px space at the bottom. I could use `padding`, but that won't work with the rest of my code.